# Why my std::set is not storing unique values?

Tags: c++, string, set

If std::set stores only unique values, then why it's not working for the below code?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

string s;
set <string> s1;
set <string>::iterator it;
getline(cin, s);
s1.insert(s);

for(it = s1.begin(); it != s1.end(); it++)
    cout<<*it;

return 0;
}
```

Input: `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

Output: `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

Is there any other way to store all the unique alphabets/elements? Can we store space also?

**EDIT:** As Robinson pointed out that I should break and store string s but when I do that like iterating through string s and inserting into set s1, its showing error.

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    s1.insert(s[i]);
```

its not working.

Comment: If you want to store unique characters then you should use a set of characters.

Comment: this is what I did, no? set is of string type.

Comment: You've inserted a single string into the set.  If you want to store individual elements, you need to break "s" down into individual letters or words.

Comment: I did but not working.

Comment: then show us the code that does the breaking

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    s1.insert(s[i]);

Comment: You are inserting one unique string. The set stores one unique string. What's the problem?

Comment: To use a set of characters, use `std::set<char>`.

Comment: Don't include <bits/stdc++.h>. It's a non standard private header not meant for inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

//#define USE_CIN // uncomment to get input from console

#ifdef USE_CIN
using std::cin;
#else
std::stringstream cin{"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"};
#endif

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::set<char> s1; // set of chars
    getline(cin, s); // get all characters into string s
    for(auto c : s)
        s1.insert(c); // insert all characters
    for(auto c : s1)
        std::cout << c; // print all characters
    return 0;
}
```